# How to get a custom section displayed in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am trying to define a custom section *levelOne* using its own counter. While everything works, I fail to make it appear in the table of contents. My code is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{levelOne}
\renewcommand{\thelevelOne}{\@arabic\c@levelOne}
\newcommand{\levelOne}{%
    \@startsection{levelOne}    % counter
    {1}                         % level one 
    {0pt}                       % parindent
    {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}  % beforeskip
    {2.3ex plus.2ex}            % afterskip
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % style
}
\newcommand*{\l@levelOne}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2em}}

\newcommand{\levelOnemark}[1]{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \levelOne{My heading 1} 
    My heading 1 content text. 
    
    \levelOne{My heading 2} 
    My heading 2 content text. 

            
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a mistake in the line with `\@dottedtocline` command, after correcting it works. The correct version is:

```
\newcommand*{\l@levelOne}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2em}}
```

*[Editor's note: I have corrected the original posting above.]*